# Is there a way to link two comments together in an IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Case: One source file has a comment in it that is directly linked to a comment in another source file (it says see line 315 in xxx.cs for more information). The problem with this approach is that the comment on line 315 may not be at that line number in the future. Is there a way to link comments together in an IDE? (currently using Visual Studio 2010, but use other IDEs from time to time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this addin (I haven't used this):

http://hyperaddin.codeplex.com/

Besides this addin, the only thing I can think of is using a file link to directly go to the linked file; something like:

```
// ...
// See file://path_to_file
//...
```

The link will be converted to an actual link that you can click using `Ctrl+Left Click` but it won't take you to a given line number - it just opens the file.

The path can be a relative file path or a full file path - full paths work best if all team members use the same folder structure in the project. For example:

`// file://w:/projects/GUI/frmMain.cs`

Comment: It looks like the hyperaddin extension doesn't work in VS2010. Appreciate the bit about adding a hyperlink.

Comment: @narohi You can download its source - it should be really simple to adapt it to VS 2010 - the addin model is the same for addins. You can also try to talk to the author if you run into issues with it. I did this with other addins - the one I patched took me about 20 minutes to convert from 2008 to 2010 when I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to a particular source file and line number is never a good idea, because someone might move things around in the other file without being aware that something is pointing at it. It's better to point at the particular type/method, for example `See DoThings() in the MyThing class.`.

In Java, using Javadoc, you can use `@link` to do this, for instance `See {@link MyThing#doThings()}`. Eclipse will automatically update these when using its refactoring tools (e.g. renaming the class or the method). If the change is done manually, Eclipse will still warn that the target of the `@link` is invalid. (There is also `@see` which is more appropriate in some situations.)

I'm not sure about C# and Visual Studio, but it's likely that its XML-based doc format offers similar functionality.

Comment: .NET has `<see cref='Class.Method'/>`

Comment: @jrummell `see cref` only works in generated documentation, not while working in the VS IDE.

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful when using Eclipse! The .Net xml doc format doesn't have much support directly in the IDE—as xxbbcc indicated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle this is to put the comment in the same file. Duplicating a comment is not the same as duplicating code, although ideally the code wouldn't need too much explanation in comments.

There are many, many reasons why the comment being in another file will cause pain. As you have stated, the line number may change but also it could be deleted (as they won't know another comment references it), updated in a way that changes its meaning and it is annoying to have to open another file in any case.